# parted created an XFS partition whereas I asked for ext4. Why?

Tags: filesystems, partition, parted

I attached a new hard drive to my computer (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64), which I can see using `sudo lshw -C disk`:

```
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST6000NM0024-1HT
       vendor: Seagate
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: SN05
       serial: Z4D90E30
       size: 5589GiB (6001GB)
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=4096
```

I created a GUID Partition Table (GPT) on it with `sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt`, which I can see:

```
username@server:~$     sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ATA ST6000NM0024-1HT (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

I then processed to create an `ext4` partition label, using `sudo parted --align optimal /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 0% 6001175MB`. I can see the new label:

```
username@server:~$     sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ATA ST6000NM0024-1HT (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  6001GB  6001GB  xfs          primary
```

How comes that the file system is `xfs`, whereas I asked it to be `ext4`?

When I created the partition afterward using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`, the partition was then marked as `ext4`, but I wonder how this `xfs` appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parted doesn't actually create a filesystem. It only creates the partition. The filesystem type that you pass to `mkpart` is not recorded anywhere.

When you ask parted to print out information, it looks at the content of the partition. It appears that you used to have an xfs filesystem in a partition starting at the same location as your current partition number 1. Since you haven't written any content to the partition yet, the old content is still there, If the xfs filesystem was less than 6001GB, and if there was really a filesystem there as opposed to a coincidence (e.g. the beginning of a filesystem image file that happened to be located exactly at that position), it's even still valid and can be mounted.

So why specify a filesystem type at all when running `mkpart`? The impact depends on the partition format. With [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitions, the filesystem type is used to determine the partition type. `ntfs` sets the partition type to the GUID used by Windows, `swap` sets the partition type to the GUID for swap, etc. The default, to which both xfs and ext4 map, is to set the GUID for Linux data. This is the same GUID regardless of the filesystem type, which makes sense since the [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) is supposed to indicate what is stored on the partition (e.g. Linux files) and not how they're organized.